# New warning in Chrome through jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

A new warning message suddenly appeared in Chrome developer tools (probably after an update) on a larger CSS+jQuery project of mine and I can't figure out what the problem might be:

> The specified value '!' does not conform to the required format. The format is '#rrggbb' where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers.

I've checked everywhere and I'm not using any '!' when specifying colors.

I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 version.

Comment: yes , i also have this problem. I think it's due to some library that i use in my projects. you use external libraries? I think it isn't a problem of jQuery

Comment: A jsfiddle or runnable snippet here would help us find the culprit.

Comment: Just in Chrome? Try another browser.

Comment: any `input[type=color]` in your code ?

Comment: yeah input[type=color] warns if specified string is an invalid string. Are you using it

Comment: Are you using some color-picker plugin like `spectrum.js`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `spectrum.js` - any further thoughts? The warning can be seen accessing the Spectrum project page at [https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case this *warning* is caused by [Spectrum.js](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) , i tried to remove it from my project and the error no longer occurs, then i think it is just that. You also use this library in your project?

This is the relative issues : [#291](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/issues/291) [#292](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/pull/292)

And this can do a fix : *replace the "!" with "#ffffff" at line 75 of spectrum.js*

```
inputTypeColorSupport = (function() { var colorInput = $("<input type='color' value='#ffffff' />")[0]; return colorInput.type === "color" && colorInput.value !== "#ffffff"; })(),
```